# How Can I download this XML file from given URL

Tags: python, xml, urllib

I'm trying to download an XML file from the following URL...

http://www.equibase.com/premium/eqbLateChangeXMLDownload.cfm

The following code, however, does not download anything except an empty file. I'm not sure how to "follow" the link above and grab the XML file that is generated. Hopefully it's possible.

```
import urllib
urlfile = "http://www.equibase.com/premium/eqbLateChangeXMLDownload.cfm"
urllib.urlretrieve(urlfile,"c:\\test.xml")
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The server employs User-Agent sniffing; it looks at the User-Agent header and if it doesn't like what it sees it'll return an empty response.

You can set the header yourself:

```
import urllib2
import shutil

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla'}
urlfile = "http://www.equibase.com/premium/eqbLateChangeXMLDownload.cfm"

request = urllib2.Request(urlfile, headers=headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
with open("c:\\test.xml", 'wb') as outfile:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response, outfile)
```

The `'Mozilla'` User-Agent string is apparently enough to convince the server to serve the file.

I used a combination of [`urllib2`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) (an updated version of the `urllib` library) and [`shutil.copyfileobj()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj) to handle setting additional headers, then copying the response data to a file. `urllib.urlretrieve()` does not support adding headers, and `urllib2` has no `urlretrieve()` equivalent.

Comment: Thanks! And also thanks for the robots heads-up. I'm probably going to download it manually now.

Comment: @TravisVOX: I misread `robots.txt`; they disallow a different path that looked a lot like yours. I removed it again, their `robots.txt` doesn't mention this URL so we can assume it is fine to crawl.

Comment: @MartijnPieters can you explain how you verify or find out that the server/page is using a User-Agent service?

Comment: ...and that setting the User Agent to `'Mozilla'` was good enough.

Comment: @Xeun: experimentation. A server is a black box, you try stuff out until it works. User-Agent sniffing is one of the first things I would try in such cases. I tried with my full User-Agent, that worked, then I cut it down to just `Mozilla` and it still worked.

Comment: @martineau: I've tried before with just `Mozilla` since most modern browser User-Agent strings start with that. In many cases, that just works.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, what is the advantage of using shutil instead of just writing the response.read()?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: `shutil` reads in chunks. This means the file is read from the socket in chunks, written to disk as you go along, without requiring that the *whole file* fits in memory. From the `shutil.copyfileobj()` documentation: *by default the data is read in chunks to avoid uncontrolled memory consumption*

Comment: so the same as using iter_content in requests?